# Rolagem bloqueado

Tags: css, slide

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho um código que é um slide que muda sozinho, más ele foi feito para rodar no background e quando coloca ele em uma página, o slide fica na tela toda, você rola o conteúdo mas o slide continua atrás,  eu queria colocar ele como background de uma div para que eu possa rolar e ele subir e não ficar atrás dos outros conteúdos. Já tentei de várias formas, mas como não manjo muito de front não consegui, então se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.
Vou deixar o link do Git

https://github.com/pericles97/BackgoundSlide_/

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu slide está *fixo* no background, então ele está

```
.slideshow {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

no seu CSS.

Remova a posição dele e deixa a default que é relative e remova o z-index também (default é auto, que é o empilhamento dos elementos na ordem em que são declarados).

Se precisar de mais ajuda, coloca o seu código pra rodar pra gente ver a apresentação.